# How do I write my own async wrapper for TcpListener?

Tags: f#, asynchronous

There is no F# async wrapper (in the PowerPack) for neither
`TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient()` nor `EndAcceptTcpClient()`.

How do I write my own wrapper around these, so that I can use the `let!` and `async` keywords and run it in parallel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked out the `Async.BuildPrimitive` function?  I think you can do something like:

```
type TcpListener with
  member x.AsyncAcceptClient() = 
    Async.BuildPrimitive(x.BeginAcceptTcpClient, x.EndAcceptTcpClient)
```

to create an extension method returning an appropriate async result.

Comment: In recent versions of F# it is called Async.FromBeginEnd.